# What is a Locale String?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I've been looking through [A re-introduction to javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript) and came across the array method toLocaleString().

I did some googling (something to do with localization?) but am having difficulty figuring it out.

What is a locale?
What's the difference between toString() and toLocaleString() in javascript?

Comment: It's like how dates or numbers are written differently amongst languages, like American (mm/dd/yyyy) vs British (dd-mm-yyyy) which can be observed with [`Date.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toString()` this will just convert the string format without any conversion at all (unless you try to overwrite it).

`toLocaleString()` will convert to string format and apply a conversion base on Locale. Example: if your Locale is set to US (U.S. English locale)

```
var number = 3500
console.log(number.toLocaleString());
```

This will print (in the console): "3,500". But if you were using only `toString()` you would get "3500" (without the comma for the thousands).

It works for currencies, dates, times, etc...

More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString